# Satisfy Imports in custom ExportProvider

Tags: mef

I'd like to know how I can have Imports in my custom ExportProvider.  Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class MyExportProvider : ExportProvider
{
    private List<Export> _exports;

    [Import()]
    private IConfig _config;

    public MyExportProvider()
       base()
    {
        _exports = new List<Export>();
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Export> GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition,
                                                          AtomicComposition composition)
    {
        if (!_exports.Any())
            Initialize();

        return _exports.Where(x => definition.IsConstraintSatisfiedBy(s.Definition);
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        var contractName = typeof(MyObject).FullName;

        var exportDefinition = new ExportDefinition(contractName, null);
        var export = new Export(exportDefinition, () => new MyObject(_config));

        _exports.Add(export);
    }
}
```

I am adding the provider when I create the CompositionContainer.

Unfortunately, the import is never satisfied.  I can see this by setting AllowDefaults = true so my provider is created, but _config is always null.

How can I configure the container and/or provider so the Import will be satisfied?

Comment: We can't reverse votes. But you can do it yourself now that it's been edited (yes, I am talking about another answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are adding your export provider you are still creating your composition container. Thus I don't see how you can use the not yet created composition container to import parts of your custom export provider.

What I would do is first create a temporary CompositionContainer that will be used to create MyExportProvider.

Afterwards use the MyExportProvider to create your second final CompositionContainer that will be used by the rest of the application.

**EDIT:**

```
    // this is your real container, only shown here for reference
    CompositionContainer container;

    public void BootstrapContainerMethod()
    {           
        // Replace this part with the catalogs required to create your export provider.
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog("./bin", "*.dll")); 

        // Your temporary container, declared here in local scope
        // will be disposed because of using
        using (var bootstrapContainer = new CompositionContainer(catalog))
        {
            var myExportProvider = bootstrapContainer.GetExportedValue<IMyExportProvider>();

            // create your real container and optionnally add catalogs (not shown here)
            container = new CompositionContainer(myExportProvider);
        }
    }
```

You might also consider the problem from another angle. Do you really need to have imports in your custom ExportProvider? I do not know your requirements, but maybe you can make do without having imports.

Comment: Are there any performance or memory concerns having nested containers like this?

Comment: I wouldn't use a nested container, I will edit my answer with an example.

Comment: But doesn't that mean MEF has to go through the 'discovery' process twice?

Comment: Yes it does, but it's two different containers. The time to create a container with it's catalog is not that much. Particularly if your bootstrap container only has the catalogs it needs to have. In my current project, a new container is created (and disposed) on each service call (for reasons I will not expose here). The performance has not been a problem. If your main container is exposed in a singleton or something similar, you will only have to pay this minimal cost when the container is first created. I can see the design problem if you are creating new containers every time like myself.

Comment: Any reason why I couldn't/shouldn't use the same catalog object when creating the second container? In my case, they will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the dual `CompositionContainer` solution, you could wire this up in a single export provider, and have it compose itself using the same container. As an example, I've defined the following contract and it's export:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string message);
}

[Export(typeof(ILogger))]
public class ConsoleLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

And with my example `ExportProvider`, I expect to be able to import an instance of it:

```
public class TestExportProvider : ExportProvider
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    private bool _initialised;

    [Import]
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public void SetCompositionService(ICompositionService service)
    {
        if (service == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("service");

        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (!_initialised)
            {
                InitialiseProvider(service);
            }
        }
    }

    private void InitialiseProvider(ICompositionService service)
    {
        service.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);
        _initialised = true;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Export> GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
    {
        if (_initialised)
        {
            Logger.Log("Getting available exports for '" + definition.ContractName + "'");

            // Do work here.);
            return Enumerable.Empty<Export>();
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<Export>();
    }
}
```

I provide an instance of an `ICompositionService`, which `CompositionContainer` implements, and I perform a first-time initialisation when I call `SetCompositionService`. It checks to see if it has already been initialised, and if not, goes ahead and calls the `SatisfyImportsOnce` method on itself.

We would wire this up, something like this:

```
// Build our catalog.
var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly);

// Create our provider.
var provider = new TestExportProvider();

// Create our container.
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog, provider);

// Register the composition service to satisfy it's own imports.
provider.SetCompositionService(container);
```

Obviously you wouldn't be able to use any imports and your `ExportProvider` will explicitly create for you, but for everything else, it should work.