# Prism / MEF - When to download list of modules to load

Tags: c#, .net, prism, mef

I am converting a project to Prism/MEF and need to download the list of modules from a central db

however the "list downloader" instance Reference is set to null so assuming the code is not in the right place

Here's the flow

```
public class Bootstrapper : MefBootstrapper {
    [Import]
    IMyList  sync1 { get; set; }

    ...
    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog() {
        **sync1.Sync();             // sync1 is null**

        AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(....)
    }
    ...
}


[Export(typeof(IMyList))]
private class DBSync : IMyList {
     [Import] IDBConn mydb { get; set; }
     public void Sync(){ 
         // connects to mydb and gets a list of auth modules for the current user
     }
}
```

the prob is sync1 iS NULL !! why ?

I know i am doing something wrong but this is my 1st prism project from scratch so pls go easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using sync1 to configure your catalogs. Is it possible you haven't composed your parts yet ?

For Bootstrapper's parts to be compsosed it needs to be instantiated by MEF, for example by using GetExportedValue<>, otherwise IMyList will be null.

If so you will need to change your code so that MEF already has a part for IMyList in it's catalog, and then add additional parts.

If this is not your problem, another possible source of the problem could be a composition error when satisfying one of DBSync imports, ie:

```
[Import] IDBConn mydb { get; set; }
```

In this case you should get an exception. You could try running the program in debug while setting the option to break on all Common Language Runtime Exceptions.

**EDIT :**

If your container is null it won't be able to compose the imports in your bootstrapper class. MEf imports it's components when it instantiate the class. You can't rely on imports being available before the container is created.

You will have to :

Change IMyList sync1 so that's it's not an import anymore.

If you really need to have your IMyList composed by MEF, you will need to create a temporary container (no need to use the MefBootStrapper) and use this temporary container just to compose the parts in your bootstrapper class. You can dispose it afterwards. See this other answer ([Satisfy Imports in custom ExportProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507242/satisfy-imports-in-custom-exportprovider/8582137#8582137)).

I would really recommend going with the first option tough, changing sync1 so it's not an import, unless you have a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: problem is Container is null in Bootstrapper.ConfigureModuleCatalog() where the list of modules needs to be loaded after retrieval using Sync()

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you have not exported IMyList. Therefor I think you need to put an export attribute on the line before private class DBCon

I hope this helps...

Nigel...

Comment: sorry, updated the ques, it was done in code but not shown in ques